# Stuck on storing individual rows from the sqlDataReader for later use

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sqldatareader

I am using Visual Studio, Winforms and the integrated SQL Server.

The win form is simple it contains one textbox and 3 buttons.

I have two tables in SQL Server :

- `Questions` &
- `Answers`

I would like for a question from the question table to be loaded into the textbox,
and I want the 3 answers from the answers table to be loaded into the button text

I have been able to get this working using the `sqlDataReader` and using

```
while Datareader.read() 
{
     txtBox.text = DataReader.getValue()
```

etc

However I have been unable to stop the `dataReader` from reading up until the last result, I call `dataReader` in the forms `onload()` event so I need a way of saving the results stream from the `dataReader` to a object or list that I can access to make a simple question and answer form, also in the form there is no right/wrong answers, simply choosing an option should display the next row from the SQL Server tables mentioned above, any help or advice is greatly appreciated, sorry if this does not make sense.

Comment: I don't think your code even compile, so stoping the dataReader is not your biggest problem. Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and elaborate where you stuck.

Comment: the code does compile, the code above is the simplest way i could think of putting my problem, getting the data from the data reader works i just want to store each row from the data reader in a list or something similar so i can access as needed without having to query my sql tables every time i want the sql data, i gather i probably supposed to do this with a while loop but i cant seem to figure out how, im really new to c#, thanks for taking the time to comment.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use a `while` loop to put the questions into the text box. From the fragment of code you have provided, it looks like it will just loop through all questions rapidly and only the last question will end up being displayed.

Create a couple of member variables:

```
public List<string> _questions = new List<string>();
public int _questionsIndex = 0;
```

In your `onload` event, store the questions in the list:

```
while Datareader.read() 
{
    _questions.Add(DataReader.getValue());
```

And then show the first question and increment your index:

```
txtBox.text = _questions[_questionIndex];
_questionIndex++;
```

Now the next time you are ready to show a new question, you just have to do the same thing:

```
txtBox.text = _questions[_questionIndex];
_questionIndex++;
```